# Why is there a sudden drop-off in half-life of isotopes at around 130 neutrons? Is there a name for this?

Tags: nuclear-physics, stability, binding-energy, isotopes, half-life

Pertaining to the chart of nuclides, there is a region above Bismuth, in which the relatively continuous trend of stability is interrupted by a batch of isotopes all with extremely short half-lives. I know that "magic numbers" contribute to the stability of nuclei via shell-filing, is there such a thing as an "anti-magic" number which leads to this "bay of instability" style feature? I assume this is a well studied phenomenon, I just know not what keywords to look for in order to look into it further.

[image: the area in question]

I find it particularly fascinating as it is so close to the last few stable elements, the drop-off in half-life is precipitous and it affects a lot of isotopes in this area. Is it something to do with how alpha decay operates? Every isotope in this loosely-defined zone seems to undergo alpha decay. I also note that generally, above Bismuth the 128-neutron line is extremely unstable, with half-lives much more gradually increasing as $N$ increases.

Answer (score 7):

The instability is actually centred on N=128 neutrons, not N=130, and is caused by N=126 being a neutron [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(physics)).  Isotopes with magic numbers of neutrons have greater binding energies than those that don't, so it is energetically favourable for isotopes with N=128 to decay to an N=126 isotope by [alpha decay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_decay). This causes a peak in alpha decay energy ($Q_\alpha$) at 128 neutrons and corresponding dip in half-life ($t_{1/2}$), as shown in [Figure 3](https://ars.els-cdn.com/content/image/1-s2.0-S0370269317309942-gr003_lrg.jpg) from [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0370269317309942).  According to the [Geiger-Nuttall Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geiger%E2%80%93Nuttall_law), the half-life for alpha decays decreases exponentially with increasing $\sqrt{Q_\alpha}$.

I don't know if the dip has a name.

Comment: Fascinating! So due to the relative stability of N=126, anything close to it very rapidly wants to decay down to (or near to) that. Would also explain why N=127 isotopes are minorly more stable, they cannot simply undergo a single alpha decay to N=126. I would suppose there are similar effects on half-lives near other magic numbers, though the half-lives are generally greater for lighter elements so the effect is probably far less pronounced.